# What does align mean in turtle?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Can someone please explain when align= "center" mean and also what font means?

```
pen.write("How are you? ", align="center", font=("Courier", 15, "bold"))
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.write) might be helpful. The `font` argument specifies a particular font, size, and type, and is not much different from how fonts work in your favourite text editor.

Comment: It means how the letters of the text string will be placed relative to the current turtle position.

Answer (score 0):

`align="center"` means to center text in the X dimension.

`font` is obviously the font of your text. Parameters are font name, font size and font style. So `font=("Courier", 15, "bold"))` means the font is Courier, size is 15 and it will be **bold**.

[image: Alignment]

Comment: What do you mean by x dimension? I am kind of new to programming.

Comment: See the image in my updated answer, hope that makes sense. https://i.stack.imgur.com/79EQC.png

Answer (score 0):

```
pen.write("How are you? ", align="center", font=("Courier", 15, "bold"))
```

Here, Align means where are you put "How are you" the words on the main screen

And, Second thing is font. Font means the style of your font .

```
pen.write("How are you ? ", align="left", font=("Arial", 20, "italic")
```

This is another way of writing where your font put in the left side on the main screen and style of my font is "Arial".